# Minimizing costs of a specific geometry shape

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, spheres

I have geometry mathematical problem. I have a shape that is made of a cylinder and two half spheres as to top and bottom. How can I minimize the cost of this shape when the volume is known and the cylinder part costs $k_1$ dollar per square meters and the sphere part costs $k_2$ dollar per square meter.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It will help someone answer your question if you tell us what you already know.  What are the variables you can control?  Do you know the formulas for the surface area and volume of these solids?  Can you give formulas for the known volume and for the cost you are trying to minimize?

Comment: @Théophile I tried using the equations for the volume of the shapes, but then I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Is Lagrange multipliers method supposed to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the volume of that shape is given by:

$$\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{V}_\text{cylinder}+\mathcal{V}_\text{hemisphere}+\mathcal{V}_\text{hemisphere}=\mathcal{V}_\text{cylinder}+\mathcal{V}_\text{sphere}\tag1$$

Now, for the volume of a cylinder:

$$\mathcal{V}_\text{cylinder}=\pi\cdot\text{r}_\text{cylinder}^2\cdot\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}\tag2$$

And for the sphere:

$$\mathcal{V}_\text{sphere}=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}_\text{sphere}^3\tag3$$

Now, we also know that:

$$\text{r}=\text{r}_\text{cylinder}=\text{r}_\text{sphere}\tag4$$

So the total volume is given by:

$$\mathcal{V}=\pi\cdot\text{r}^2\cdot\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+\frac{4}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}^3=\frac{\pi\text{r}^2}{3}\cdot\left(3\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+4\text{r}\right)\tag5$$

And the surface area is given by:

$$\mathcal{S}=2\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}\cdot\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+4\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}^2\tag6$$

And for the costs we can set up a function:

$$\mathcal{K}=\text{K}_1\cdot2\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}\cdot\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+\text{K}_2\cdot4\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}^2\tag7$$

Well, you know the volume:

$$\mathcal{V}=\frac{\pi\text{r}^2}{3}\cdot\left(3\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+4\text{r}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}=\frac{\mathcal{V}}{\pi\text{r}^2}-\frac{4\text{r}}{3}\tag8$$

So, in order to minimize the costs we can write:

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{K}}{\partial\text{r}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{r}}\left\{\text{K}_1\cdot2\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}\cdot\left(\frac{\mathcal{V}}{\pi\text{r}^2}-\frac{4\text{r}}{3}\right)+\text{K}_2\cdot4\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}^2\right\}=$$
$$8\text{K}_2\pi\text{r}-\frac{16\text{K}_1\pi\text{r}}{3}-\frac{2\text{K}_1\mathcal{V}}{\text{r}^2}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{r}=\left(\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{\text{K}_1\mathcal{V}}{\pi\text{K}_2-\frac{2\pi\text{K}_1}{3}}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\tag9$$

And so the height will be:

$$\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}=2\cdot\left(\frac{6}{\pi}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\text{K}_2}{\text{K}_1}-1\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\text{K}_1\mathcal{V}}{3\text{K}_2-2\text{K}_1}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\tag{10}$$